# How to get list of words in the DB column separated by comma and compare them with user input?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a DB wherein one table, the column has a list of words separated by the comma, which has to be compared and select accordingly. but in PHP so far I have written SQL code for one word in a column cell-like,

```
<?PHP 
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'name'";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) { 
       while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
?>
```

but here, I have a list of words in the name column separated by a column. 
how do I write code to extract all those words into single and check each one of them with the user input text?

Hope I m clear, Any help is appreciated..

Comment: _"the column has a list of words separated by the comma"_ - can't you change that to a normalized database design? Because right now you are struggeling with the result of a bad db design.

Comment: no, they are keywords and they has to be an array

Comment: still, they can live in a seperate table, as they should.

Comment: you could use `WHERE name LIKE '%name%'`. But that can again lead to unwanted results, is slower than a relational table, doesn't enable you to search for 2 strings, ..

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter_input()` for Input,
use `explode()` for Input,
use SQL IN or SQL REGEX with and/or for SQL Part.

```
$clean_userinput = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "userinput", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

like $_GET["userinput"]

```
$array_userinput = explode(" ", $clean_userinput); 
$in = "(";

for($i=0;$i <count($array_userinput); $i++) {
    $in .= "'" . trim($array_userinput[$i]) . "'";
}

$in .= ")"
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN ". $in;
```

That all magic simple. php.net is your best source.